# Combine multiple arrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays

I'm working with multiple lists and I want to combine then like the example below:

`listone = ['firstname', 'secondname', ...]
listtwo = ['phoneone', 'phonetwo', ...]
listthree = ['adressone', 'adresstwo', ...]`

Take these listsand put the elements together:

`another_listone = ['firstname', 'phoneone', 'adressone']
another_listtwo = ['secondname', 'phonetwo', 'adresstwo']`

I tried to append then with a for, but these lists have a lot of data and my code always crash. Someone could help?

Comment: These are not arrays, they are *lists*.

Comment: You can `zip` and retrieve them lazily:`itertools.izip(arrayone, arraytwo, arraythree)`